# Allocate a polymorphic class member at a specific location?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, malloc, new-operator

I have a class with a few class members and a polymorphic member:

```
class Container{

    Container::Container(){ p = new Derived();}

    Poly* p;
    A a;
    B b;
};
```

I would like to allocate the memory for the actual polymorphic object `Container::p` points to, contiguously after `Container::b`, rather than via the default `new()` and therefore `malloc()`.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Does it _have_ to be through `new`? Polymorphism works with references too. Also `new != malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

To some extent the details depend on how the `Container` constructor decides on the concrete type of `Poly`. Presumably this choice can vary. Otherwise, just declare a `Derived` member right after `b`.

But assuming that the question makes sense, you'll just have to use placement new, and make sure `Container` can only be allocated dynamically. Be careful about alignment! Happily C++11 added support for that.

A good way to make sure that `Container` is only allocated dynamically is to make the destructor inaccessible to client code.

For the allocation size I would probably define a custom allocation function (`operator new`) in class `Container`, passing arguments sufficient to determine the total object size.

But again, the details of that depend on the concrete case you have: the question is under-specified.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done with a placement new.

```
class Container{

    Container(){ p = new(polyAlloc) Derived(); }

    ~Container(){ p->~Poly(); /* required for placement new */ }

    Poly* p;
    A a;
    B b;
    char polyAlloc[1024]; // where the size is the max size a derived class can be
};
```

Comment: Interesting.  Except that there could be an alignment issue, on some architectures. Why not a union of suche an array and a Derived ?

Comment: **−1** Fails to consider alignment issues and other issues; fails to illustrate how to use placement `new` correctly; adds a needless max size restriction; conveys a dangerous impression of triviality; the given code is generally UB.